# REST: PUT and how to handle partial entity

Tags: rest, partial, put

I've read all about idem potency of PUT and not to use it for partial updates. My question now is how to handle such situations.

Assume my service gets a PUT request for Resource A. A has 5 properties. What do I do if the request only contains 4 of those?

- Set the missing property to null
- throw error, 400 Bad Request
- other?

Setting to null seems ok when creating a new resource but seems possibly problematic or dangerous when updating.

Which is considered "best practice" for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Book REST in Practice:

- PUT expects the entire resource representation
- PATCH has been suggested for use in situations—typically involving large resource
  representations where only changes are provided

Answer (score 1):

If the missing parameter is a mandatory one, obviously you should return `HTTP 400`. If the parameter is not mandatory you can create your resource with another parameters passed.

I think this is also valid for the **update** case. If there is a missing mandatory parameter, you should return `HTTP 400`. Otherwise, go on with the existing parameters.

This is what I do and I think it is a reasonable approach.